# How to turn text labels in Chronosys LaTeX

Tags: time, latex, timeline, arch, fgarch

I need to turn for 45º my text in my timeline in LaTeX:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{chronology}
\usepackage{chronosys}

\begin{document}

\startchronology
\chronoevent{1982}{ARCH $\Rightarrow$ \newline Robert Engle~\cite{engle}} 
\chronoevent{1986}{GARCH $\Rightarrow$ \newline Tim Bollerslev~\cite{bollerslev}}
\stopchronology

\end{document}
```

How did I can do it?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `\rotatebox`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{chronosys}
%\usepackage{chronology}


\begin{document}

\startchronology
\chronoevent{1986}{\rotatebox{45}{GARCH $\Rightarrow$ Tim Bollerslev~\cite{bollerslev}}}
\stopchronology

\end{document}
```

[image]